# Use grep only on specific columns in many files?

Tags: bash, grep

Basically, I have one file with patterns and I want every line to be searched in all text files in a certain directory. I also only want exact matches. The many files are zipped.

However, I have one more condition. I need the first two columns of a line in the pattern file to match the first two columns of a line in any given text file that is searched. If they match, the output I want is the pattern(the entire line) followed by all the names of the text files that a match was found in with their entire match lines (not just first two columns).

An output such as:

```
pattern1
file23:"text from entire line in file 23 here"
file37:"text from entire line in file 37 here"
file156:"text from entire line in file 156 here"
pattern2
file12:"text from entire line in file 12 here"
file67:"text from entire line in file 67 here"
file200:"text from entire line in file 200 here"
```

I know that grep can take an input file, but the problem is that it takes every pattern in the pattern file and searches for them in a given text file before moving onto the next file, which makes the above output more difficult. So I thought it would be better to loop through each line in a file, print the line, and then search for the line in the many files, seeing if the first two columns match.

I thought about this:

```
cat pattern_file.txt | while read line
do
  echo $line >> output.txt
  zgrep -w -l $line many_files/*txt >> output.txt
done
```

But with this code, it doesn't search by the first two columns only. Is there a way so specify the first two columns for both the pattern line and for the lines that grep searches through?

What is the best way to do this? Would something other than grep, like awk, be better to use? There were other questions like this, but none that used columns for both the search pattern and the searched file.

Few lines from pattern file:

```
1 5390182 . A C 40.0 PASS DP=21164;EFF=missense_variant(MODERATE|MISSENSE|Aag/Cag|p.Lys22Gln/c.64A>C|359|AT1G15670|protein_coding|CODING|AT1G15670.1|1|1) 
1 5390200 . G T 40.0 PASS DP=21237;EFF=missense_variant(MODERATE|MISSENSE|Gcc/Tcc|p.Ala28Ser/c.82G>T|359|AT1G15670|protein_coding|CODING|AT1G15670.1|1|1) 
1 5390228 . A C 40.0 PASS DP=21317;EFF=missense_variant(MODERATE|MISSENSE|gAa/gCa|p.Glu37Ala/c.110A>C|359|AT1G15670|protein_coding|CODING|AT1G15670.1|1|1)
```

Few lines from a file in searched files:

```
1   10699576    .   G   A   36  PASS    DP=4    GT:GQ:DP    1|1:36:4
1   10699790    .   T   C   40  PASS    DP=6    GT:GQ:DP    1|1:40:6
1   10699808    .   G   A   40  PASS    DP=7    GT:GQ:DP    1|1:40:7
```

They both in reality are much larger.

Comment: Whenever you're talking about comparing columns or fields the command you want is `awk`, not `grep`, since awk is designed to work on fields and grep isn't. You have a **lot** of information in your question - if you can reduce it to (or add) just a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output then you'll get more people willing to read that to try to help you.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like this might be what you want:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]; next} ($1,$2) in a' patternfile anyfile
```

If it's not then update your question to provide a clear, simple statement of your requirements and concise, testable sample input and expected output that demonstrates your problem and that we could test a potential solution against.

if `anyfile` is actually a zip file then you'd do something like:

```
zcat anyfile | awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]; next} ($1,$2) in a' patternfile -
```

Replace `zcat` with whatever command you use to produce text from your zip file if that's not what you use.

Per the question in the comments, if both input files are compressed and your shell supports it (e.g. bash) you could do:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]; next} ($1,$2) in a' <(zcat patternfile) <(zcat anyfile)
```

otherwise just uncompress patternfile to a tmp file first and use that in the awk command.

Comment: Can I use awk to output the file name that the match is found in?

Comment: Of course but if you want that then you should show in the expected output in your question.

Comment: @EdMorton what would you do if the patternfile is gzipped?

Comment: @EdMorton I understood this for anyfile but I meant the patternfile

Comment: I tried this:
zcat anyfile | awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]; next} ($1,$2) in a' $zcat(patternfile) -
but this Error arose: gzip: invalid option -- '0'

Comment: @IvoLeist I updated my answer to show one approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use `read` to parse the pattern file's columns and add an anchor to the `zgrep` pattern :

```
while read -r column1 column2 rest_of_the_line
do
  echo "$column1 $column2 $rest_of_the_line" 
  zgrep -w -l "^$column1\s*$column2" many_files/*txt
done < pattern_file.txt >> output.txt
```

`read` is able to parse lines into multiple variables passed as parameters, the last of which getting the rest of the line. It will separate fields around characters of the `$IFS` Internal Field Separator (by default tabulations, spaces and linefeeds, can be overriden for the `read` command by using `while IFS='...' read ...`).

Using `-r` avoids unwanted escapes and makes the parsing more reliable, and `while ... do ... done < file` performs a bit better since it avoids an useless use of `cat`. Since the output of all the commands inside the while is redirected I also put the redirection on the `while` rather than on each individual commands.

Comment: For some reason, the variables "column1" "column2" and "rest_of_the_line" are empty for me when I run this code. If I write `echo $column1` after `do`, it prints an empty line.

Comment: @ChaseLewis can you add an extract of your patterns file to your question?

Comment: What do you mean by extract exactly? How do I do this

Comment: I meant to copy paste a few lines of your patterns file if possible, or something closely ressembling if it's sensible data. Put it in a code block inside your question for better formatting. You can also try [this ideone](https://ideone.com/YbNR8s) on your data to see if it parses correctly (fork, put a few lines of your file in the stdin and execute to see if it's properly parsed). Also make sure you didn't forget to add the `< filename` by the end of the `while` loop

Comment: Ok I added some lines that should be helpful.

Comment: Actually, it is parsing correctly. My pattern file had an empty space at the top which was messing things up... oops. But now it is not outputing any matches. I know there is at least one match for each pattern.

Comment: @ChaseLewis I've updated my answer to allow multiple spaces and/or tabulation between the two fields in the target files, previously it only matched if there was a single space between them. Ed Morton's comment that `awk` would be more appropriate is right too, although I think you'd need to handle the decompression separately